# Vite - Rollup node_modules not defined as modules

Tags: node-modules, rollupjs, vite

I have a Webpack project which I am migrating to Vite. I have the dev server working, and now I am trying to get the build to work. I have run into an issue where a number of my dependencies cannot be imported as modules because they must be global. This includes Backbone, jQuery, moment.js, and DevExtreme. (I will be slowly getting rid of these dependencies, but for now, there is a large code base which is based on them)

I first tried to have them loaded as modules and manually add them to the global context, but that failed because when `import`ing you can't manage the order in which the files are loaded. Backbone and DevExtreme require jQuery to be loaded in first. If it isn't, the page fails to load.

So I have a list of node_modules referenced directly from my html entry points.

Here is a simplified example of what I currently have.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <title>rollup test</title>
    <script src="/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

oldMain.js

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").append("Here is some text");
});
```

main.ts

```js
import './oldMain.js';
```

vite.config.ts

```js
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        index: path.resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
      },
    }
  }
});
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "issue-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-tsc --noEmit && vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.33",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.34.10",
  }
}
```

At the moment, the only way forward that I can see is to write a rollup plugin that extracts the list of non-module scripts from the html file, gets the target files from their paths, copies them to the dist/assets directory, and changes the src paths in the html to the new location.

Is there a better way? A plugin that already exists that knows how to do this? Is there a different way to include these dependencies so they will be globally available?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up going with is:

1. I use handlebars to create the `index.html` file the necessary scripts.
2. Have a `.ts` file which decides what scripts need to be in the `index.html` file. It checks whether the current build is `dev` or `prod` and puts the relevant path in for each script.

My `index.html` looks like:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    [... meta, base, title, link, etc.]

    {{{injectScripts externalScripts}}}
  </head>
  <body>
    [... etc]
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a simple handlebars plugin called `injectScripts` which simply does that - it puts the scripts in where I call the it in the html. Not my favorite solution to a problem, but it works well enough.